# Different between ways of setting default date format in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date-format

In Rails 3, is there any difference between

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%m/%d/%Y'
```

(which has been suggested all over the Internet but does not seem to work--I get a stack trace when starting my server)

and

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%m/%d/%Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions` is not a valid constant anymore.  I believe some Rails components were renamed in the transition to 3.1.

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%m/%d/%Y'
```

Seems to work for me in Rails 3.1.  I also changed `Time::DATE_FORMATS` and `DateTime::DATE_FORMATS` similarly.